# Latex Sublime Text Snippet doesn't working

Tags: sublime-text, code-snippets

i'm using Sublime snippet to create a state machine template. However, it does nothing. I don't understand why, as all my other snippet are working fine.

If a remove some lines in the snippet, it work, but i need the whole block :/

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4.5cm,on grid,auto]

        \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20] % Node color

        \node[state,initial,initial text=reset, initial where=below] (configuration) {$conf$}; % Node name and position
        \node[state] (init) [below right=of configuration] {$init$};

        \path[->] % Arrow
        (configuration)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {finishConfiguration=1} (init)

        (init)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {} (configuration);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>stmach</tabTrigger> 
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>text.tex</scope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer: add a "\" before every "$".

=1pt,node distance=4.5cm,on grid,auto]

```
        \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20] % Node color

        \node[state,initial,initial text=reset, initial where=below] (configuration) {$conf$}; % Node name and position
        \node[state] (init) [below right=of configuration] {\$init\$};

        \path[->] % Arrow
        (configuration)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {finishConfiguration=1} (init)

        (init)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {} (configuration);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>stmach</tabTrigger> 
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>text.tex</scope>
```